# Access array items and finding their length

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a table on an html page using `knockout`. The table headers and columns can vary.
I'm using an `Array` containing other `Arrays` and looping through.

Here is an example:

`Array` is not `observable`

```
var Headers = ["Name", "Course", "DateofBirth"];
var Columns = ["John", "Math", "23/05/1979"]
self.Person.push(Headers);
self.Person.push(Columns);
```

Each `Person` got the above `Arrays`

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko if: value().Persons.length > 0  -->
<!-- ko foreach: value().Persons-->
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: Headers -->
        <th data-bind="text: $data">
        </th>
        <!--/ko-->
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <!-- ko if:  Columns.length <= 3 -->
      <tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: Columns -->
        <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
        <!--/ko-->
      </tr>
      <!--/ko-->

      <!-- ko ifnot: Columns.length > 3 -->
      <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
      </tr>
      <!--/ko-->

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

So `Persons` is the main `Array` and within it there is `Headers` and `Columns`. The reason why I'm checking `Columns` size is to add more `<td>` if there is more than three columns, so I end up with having `$data` corresponding to each `header`.

If `Columns` is less than or equal to three, then create one `<td>` with the data. Otherwise, create multiple `<td>` with the data.

I'm getting an error in Console saying **Cannot read property 'length' of null**

I'm handling the position of `Columns` items under each header through a `javascript` which splits the `Columns` into equal chunks based on the `Headers` size. So each item in `Columns` will be, in this example, a size of three.

Not sure if I'm missing something. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Can you please create a [runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) or [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)? I have added a basic skeleton of the view model. Please update it with a minimal version of your code

Comment: Also, the closing tag for `<!-- ko if: value().Persons.length > 0  -->` and `<!-- ko foreach: value().Persons-->` is missing from your HTML

Comment: Your `tr` creation is a bit confusing. How does `Columns` look when there are more than one row? Something like this `["John", "Math", "23/05/1979", "Jane", "Science", "1/1/2000"]`? Do you manually create the `Columns` data from an array of objects? Because, if you have an array of objects, you can directly create `tr` and `td` without creating this `Columns` array. Relying on length of the data and it's index to identify it's position could lead to errors.

Comment: @adiga I'm not relying on the data and index in the `Columns` Array to determine position. I just want to know `Columns` size to determine whether to add more `<td`> or not. If `Columns` size is less than or equal to three, then display all data with one `<td>`. If greater then three, create more `<td>`. Without the `if` conditions, `Columns` greater than three will be displayed and squashed in one `<td>` which is not proper.

Comment: @adiga so in your example `Columns` is more than three. So in `html` it will be showing like this 
`<tr>`
`<td>John Math 23/05/1979</td> `
`<td>Jane Science 1/1/2000</td>`
`</tr>`

Comment: That will create 1 row with 2 columns. But the header has 3 columns called `"Name", "Course", "DateofBirth"`. In the question you have mentioned *"If Columns is less than or equal to three, then create one <tr> with the data. Otherwise, create multiple <tr> with the data"*. I thought it would create `<tr><td>John</td><td>Math</td><td>1979</td></tr> <tr><td>Jane</td> <td>Science</td><td>1/1/2000</td></tr>`

Comment: @adiga yes 1 row with 2 columns. In the question I meant `<td>`'s instead of `<tr>`'s. I've edited it.

Comment: But, that would display wrong data. Under `Name` column, all of John's data would populate and under `Course` column, all of Jane's data would populate. And `DateofBirth` column will be empty.

Comment: @adiga Ok. Do you know why I can't access the length property then?